# Why does software updater insist on reinstalling mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, update-manager

I just switched to Xenial. I can't use mysql 5.7 (have to be slave to a 5.1 server, and 5.7 isn't compatible with 5.1), so I uninstalled it, purged it, then installed MySQL 5.6 from Oracle's download page. All went fine.

Now, though, every time software updater runs, it says it is going to uninstall MySQL 5.6 and put back the MySQL 5.7 that I can't use. I can't do any updates because it won't let me reject only this update! "dpkg-query --list" doesn't show any trace of the old 5.7 MySQL. Why does software updater insist on doing this? How do I make it stop so I can get the rest of the updates?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent a package from being updated by running the command

```
sudo apt-mark hold package
```

In your case, it should run

```
sudo apt-mark hold mysql5.6
```

If you wish to update it later, you can run

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package
```